# why I cannot use ng-material directive with other directives in the same controller?

Tags: angularjs

```js
 var firstApp=angular.module("firstApp",['ngMaterial','ngResource','ngRoute']);

firstApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)
{

$routeProvider.

when('/homepage',{
    templateUrl : 'D:\SnackBox\homepage.html'
}).
when('/signup',{
templateUrl : 'D:\SnackBox\homepage2.html'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo:'/homepage'
});
}]);
```

Comment: can you show how are you adding them? the _square bracket_ is an array, which is comma (`,`) separated. E.g. `['ngMaterial', 'another.module']`

Comment: var firstApplication = angular.module("firstApplication", ['ngMaterial','ngRoute']);

Comment: do you have any errors in console? can you also show your scripts?

Comment: I have used <ng-view></ng-view> in html with two templates with id as homepage.html and homepage2.html   and imported routing , angular and material injections